# Is it possible to create a Powershell runspace restricted to a folder

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell host with a restricted runspace. I would like to give access to commands like Get-ChildItem but restricted to a certain folder and all it's subfolders. Is there a way to apply such a restriction to a runspace, or can you only restrcit to langiage features and available commands?

Comment: The only way I can think of off the top of my head would to be run as a user with restricted permissions in the runspace.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/benshy/archive/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-amp-elevate-the-process.aspx

Comment: You could create a [proxy function for Get-ChildItem](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/01/create-a-proxy-function-to-display-registry-key-time-stamps.aspx) and filter allowed paths inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [beatcracker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424236/beatcracker), create a proxy function for `Get-ChildItem`. You don't actually need to make `Get-ChildItem` available in the runspace; if you hide a cmdlet or restrict its use, you can still use it inside your own functions and then allow your function to be run.

Comment: Yes, this sounds good. I will try to implement that. Found New-CommandWrapper (http://poshcode.org/2197) which could help in doing the job. More details at: https://books.google.nl/books?id=78w1953mptUC&lpg=PA108&ots=z0svnP37RJ&dq=New-CommandWrapper&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q=New-CommandWrapper&f=false